# how can I convert the values of a table into percentage values rather than absolute values?

Tags: numbers

In Numbers, how can I convert the values of a table into percentage values rather than absolute values ?

The percentage are computed per column. The sum of the cells in a column is 100%.

i.e. http://d.pr/NNwn

thanks

Comment: Can you clarify this a little? From that scree cap, it looks like you've got a bunch of integers that add up to way more than 100%. 100%=100/100=1. Unless the columns add up to one, the sum will not be 100%. Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve; I must be missing something?

Comment: @Nathan uhm. Each column has a different sum, so for column1, 100% can be a value, and for column2 100% can be another value. It doesn't have to be the same value... actually it was better if I posted just a column of values.

Comment: So, in conclusion, I probably need to sum all values and divide them by the sum and those are the percentage. Probably I don't need a number function.. but if you know a faster solution....

Comment: "Sum all values and divide them by the sum" what do you mean by that? Take the sum and divide by itself? That will give you 100%, but I don't know why you would want to do this since it's the same as just typing 1 in the cell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you could do that more or less easily:

Say for example column comedy.

The total is 534 (sum).

- 132 (1st row) is the 24.71% (132 x 100 / 534).
- 3 (2nd Row) is the 0.56%…
- 1 is the 0.18%
- 398 is the 74.53%.

The sum of 24.71+0.56+0.18+74.53 == 100% (minus rounding, add more decimals for more precision).

So if you add a final ROW with the SUM  (below technology for example) you can cause each cell to perform a Cell * 100 / TOTAL_OF_COLUMN and get your %.

What am I missing?